# How to compile and pipe the output info of a executeable file

Tags: bash, pipe, postgresql

```
....
....
checking whether gcc supports -Wl,--as-needed... yes
configure: using compiler=gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
configure: using CFLAGS=-Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror=vla -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wcast-function-type -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-stringop-truncation -O2
configure: using CPPFLAGS= -D_GNU_SOURCE
configure: using LDFLAGS=  -Wl,--as-needed
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating GNUmakefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile.global
config.status: creating src/include/pg_config.h
config.status: src/include/pg_config.h is unchanged
config.status: creating src/include/pg_config_ext.h
config.status: src/include/pg_config_ext.h is unchanged
config.status: creating src/interfaces/ecpg/include/ecpg_config.h
config.status: src/interfaces/ecpg/include/ecpg_config.h is unchanged
config.status: linking src/backend/port/tas/dummy.s to src/backend/port/tas.s
config.status: linking src/backend/port/posix_sema.c to src/backend/port/pg_sema.c
config.status: linking src/backend/port/sysv_shmem.c to src/backend/port/pg_shmem.c
config.status: linking src/include/port/linux.h to src/include/pg_config_os.h
config.status: linking src/makefiles/Makefile.linux to src/Makefile.port
```

Trying to get a rought sense, how postgresql got compiled. I want it run ./configure and also pipe the output info into a text file.

```
 sudo ./configure | /home/jian/fo1.txt
```

Error:

```
./configure: line 2885: printf: write error: Broken pipe
```

Comment: This could be helpful: [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator you search for is `>`. This redirects the output of a command to a specific device or file:

```
sudo ./configure >output_file.txt
```

If you want to capture errors (STDERR) in different file you should use:

```
 sudo ./configure >output_file.txt 2>>output_err.txt
```

If you want to append the output to existing file you should use `>>`

```
sudo ./configure >>output_file.txt
```

Comment: +1; maybe also tell the difference between `>` and `>>`

Comment: @sudodus, good point, thank you, will add it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `sudo` on your `./configure` line.

Your command should probably be:

```
./configure. |& tee home/jian/fo1.txt
```

You will probably have to clean up all the `root`-owned files you created with your previous attempt, thusly:

```
sudo find . -maxdepth 1 -user root -ls
# when you're happy with the list of files, replace `-ls` with `-delete`.
sudo find . -maxdepth 1 -user root -delete
```